# Linq union with group by perrformnces issue

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq

I have 3 Tables defined as below:

```
public Class Product
{
  public long Key {get; set;}
  public CountryKey  {get; set;}
}

public Class ProductCountry
{
  pullic long Key {get; set;}
  public long ProductKey {get; set;}
  public LocalProductKey {get; set;}
  public long CountryKey  {get; set;}
}

public Class Country
{
  public long Key {get; set;}
  public string Name  {get; set;}
}
```

I'm using EF database first, for each class we have a view to get data from database ( `VW_Product` to get the products)

I have a method filtering a collection of product depends on a criteria.

`IQueryable<VW_Product> query1 = FilterQuery(Object criteria);` gets all products matching the criteria;

Now I want concat the filtred collection by adding the folowing collection:

```
var countriesKey = new List<long>() {45, 36, 6974, 366,....};
var keys = Context.VW_ProductCountries
                  .GroupBy(pc => pc.ProductKey)
                  .Where(grp => grp.Any(pc => countriesKey.Contains(pc.CountryKey) && !grp.Any(x => x.LocalProductKey != null)))
                  .SelectMany(grp => grp.Select(pc => pc.Productkey))
                  .Distinct();

var query2 = Context.VW_Product.Where(p => keys.Contains(p.ProductKey));
var result = query1.Concat(query2);
```

Is the another way to improve this query because it takes a lot of time to execute.

Comment: It would help if your code was correct or compiled, (what's the type for `LocalProductkey`? what's `query1`? etc.), or made sense (`!grp.Any(x => x.LocalProductKey != null)` basically filters your results to `LocalProductKey == null`), in any case, it seems the query is way more convoluted than it needs to be, especially grouping which tends to result in pretty bad SQL seems to be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `.ToList()` after `.Distinct()` to transform the list of keys from an ObjectQuery to an in-memory object. In query2, you're running multiple `.Contains()` against the 'keys' ObjectQuery, possibly executing the query every time.

Also, i presume

```
var result = query1.Concat(query1);
```

should be

```
var result = query1.Concat(query2);
```